# css SVG background - strange transparent line around

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I have tried to use svg image as background-image in css. And I have faced with strange behavior. Element that has svg background has strange transparent line around.

In the example below it is shown as line between the first and the second div. Size of the line changes depending on width of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/mahnunchik/g1ux4e7o/

Screenshot from jsfiddle:

[image]

It reproduces at least in Chrome 37 and FF 32 on Windows and Linux

Svg image is quite simple:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 76" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 76">
  <path fill="#DE4943" d="M0 76L1921 0 0 0z"/>
</svg>
```

**Any idea how to fix that? Or how to explain that?**

Comment: Easiest (and in my opinion best) fix would be to simply put the actual SVG shape on your own website, instead of linking to it. Just adapt it to paste the rectangle onto that: [**info link**](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp). (I've done this some time back, my advice: make EVERYTHING relative, no absolute points! Convert if you have to) ...sidenote: in your CSS you use the color `#dc4942` instead of `#de4943`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your `<svg>` element.

Also you don't need the `enable-background` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add stroke-width="0" to the path

Comment: Attribute stroke-width="0" does not change anything. I updated example http://jsfiddle.net/mahnunchik/g1ux4e7o/